# How to get trace-id in spring-cloud-gateway using micrometer-brave

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, micrometer

I want to display traceId in logs for each request in Spring Cloud Gateway. However, traceId and spanId are just empty.

Log config is like below:

```html
logging:
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [TRACE_ID: %X{traceId:-}] [SPAN_ID: %X{spanId:-}]"
```

Part of pom.xml:

```html
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
      <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: you might put the following setting in your yml file:

spring:
  sleuth:
    reactor:
      instrumentation-type: decorate_queues

Comment: But I use micrometer instead of sleuth

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With Spring Boot 3.x and Micrometer 1.10+ you can try the following dependencies:

(Part of pom.xml)

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <artifactId>context-propagation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <version>1.10.4</version>
            <artifactId>micrometer-bom</artifactId>
            <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And in the main class of the application make the following call:

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Hooks;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
    // ...
}
```

Spring Boot should soon integrate those versions of dependencies and make the call for you, but for now these manual steps should get you the logs with tracing info.

In reactor-core [3.5.3](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/releases/tag/v3.5.3) we added automatic propagation of ThreadLocal values registered with [context-propagation](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation) (optional) library which Micrometer also uses. For those interested in the details, check the [PR](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/pull/3335) introducing this feature. This is a general enhancement from what [3.5.0](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/releases/tag/v3.5.0) brought, where the ThreadLocals were populated in special operators -> [handle](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#handle-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and [tap](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#tap-reactor.core.observability.SignalListenerFactory-) (and its overloads).

Answer (score 2):

simply explain

build.gradle

```
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
```

and As explained in the answer above

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Hooks;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
    // ...
}
```

If logback is set up well, you can check the log by doing two things.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to adding `Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation()` in the application main function, spring boot created property config which you can specify in application.properties.

spring.reactor.context-propagation with the values AUTO and LIMITED. It defaults to LIMITED.

for example (incase you need trace id and span ids):

```
spring.reactor.context-propagation: AUTO
```

Follow the entire PR history:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34201

Hope it will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

@Dariusz Jędrzejczyk's is great. There are some dependencies that you may omit as it's already covered with other dependencies. If you're using FeignClient and want to see these traces in Zipkin UI, here are the needed dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-openfeign-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
        <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-micrometer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```