# spring cloud gateway with micrometer tracing always print the same traceId?

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, micrometer

### pom

```xml
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.micrometer/micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>context-propagation</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-micrometer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-alibaba-nacos-discovery</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-gateway -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-gateway-webflux -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

### code

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CorgiApplication.class, args);
        Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
    }
```

### config

```yaml
management:
  tracing:
    enabled: true
    propagation:
      type: w3c
```

```
2023-07-04 16:13:50.105  INFO [corgi-server,64a3d4b9ee786d536d3e16ac90364c43,6d3e16ac90364c43] 41416 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] apiLog                                   : {"id":"c9969e50-2","traceId":"64a3d4b9ee786d536d3e16ac90364c43","requestIp":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","requestTime":"2023-07-04T08:13:50.096842300Z"}
2023-07-04 16:21:13.310  INFO [corgi-server,,] 41416 --- [nt-executor-206] com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [19185da9-6e6a-4306-97a1-da0b3bf173e2] Receive server push request, request = NotifySubscriberRequest, requestId = 1079
2023-07-04 16:21:13.311  INFO [corgi-server,,] 41416 --- [nt-executor-206] com.alibaba.nacos.common.remote.client   : [19185da9-6e6a-4306-97a1-da0b3bf173e2] Ack server push request, request = NotifySubscriberRequest, requestId = 1079
2023-07-04 16:21:18.483  INFO [corgi-server,64a3d4b9ee786d536d3e16ac90364c43,6d3e16ac90364c43] 41416 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] apiLog                                   : {"id":"c9969e50-3","traceId":"64a3d4b9ee786d536d3e16ac90364c43","requestIp":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","requestTime":"2023-07-04T08:21:18.472307900Z"}
```

different request now always get the same traceId, how can that be happened.

ref:
[How to get trace-id in spring-cloud-gateway using micrometer-brave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221864/how-to-get-trace-id-in-spring-cloud-gateway-using-micrometer-brave)

now i dont now whats wrong , i hava no idea with it.

Answer (score 2):

Please never try to define the versions on your own and let the Boot BOM figure it out for you. What I think you are trying to do should work out of the box if you are using the right versions (I assume this is Boot 3.x).

Answer (score 0):

it seems i have to put traceid and spanid into MDC myself? Is that the best answer?

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TraceFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
    private final Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        String traceId = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(TRACE_ID);
        String spanId;
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(traceId)) {
            TraceContext traceContext = tracer.nextSpan().context();
            traceId = traceContext.traceId();
            spanId = traceContext.spanId();
            final List<String> traceParam = new ArrayList<>();
            traceParam.add(traceId);
            ServerHttpRequest newRequest = exchange.getRequest().mutate().headers(httpHeaders ->
                    httpHeaders.put(TRACE_ID, traceParam)
            ).build();
            exchange.mutate().request(newRequest);
        } else {
            TraceContext context = tracer.traceContextBuilder().traceId(traceId).build();
            Span span = tracer.spanBuilder().setParent(context).start();
            tracer.withSpan(span);
            spanId = context.spanId();
        }
        MDC.put("traceId", traceId);
        MDC.put("spanId", spanId);
        RequestContext record = exchange.getAttribute(REQUEST_CONTEXT);
        record.setTraceId(traceId);
        Mono<Void> result = chain.filter(exchange);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return CorgiFilters.TRACE.getOrder();
    }
}
```